# First Startup on a vb app

Tags: vb.net, startup

I want to make an app which you make a password and username and use it for the app but I only want this screen to open the first time you load the app so after the first load it goes right to the login screen

sorry I am a complete n00b at vb

I am using vb.net

I do not know how do any thing like store info nor am I knowedgable about SQL servers

I have basic knowlegde but not enough

this is not going to be a full blown app I am just trying to learn some new skills

so I am not going to worry about making new passwords or usernames and storing them for each individual user

I was just hopeing on learning how to make a login screen of some sort

THIS IS FOR EDUCATION PURPOSES ONLY THIS IS NOT GOING TO BE PUBLISHED

Comment: What if the username/password creation screen pops up, and I close out before I create a username?  Should it pop up again next time I start the app, or go straight to the login screen?  What happens if I'm at a different computer that hasn't had the program run before, but I already have a username and password?

Comment: I think you should update your question with these requirements. In this case you need a shared authentication provider. Things such as windows or perhaps SQL server may be the way forward in this case. Unless of course you can secure access to a file share and use this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the information is the users profile or a known directory (encrypted of course) and then look for it before the showing the dialog. If its there, just read the info.

Comment: were would I store the info that I take from them